# Xcode generated umbrella header for framework does not import Foundation when @objc inference is turned off

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a framework written entirely in Swift, and it's included in an app that uses a mix of Objective-C and Swift, i.e.

```
#import "MyFramework-Swift.h"
```

If `Swift 3 @objc inference` is turned `ON` for the framework target then everything compiles and runs fine. If `Swift 3 @objc inference` is turned `OFF` then the framework itself will compile, but the file that it's included in does not and spits out a bunch of errors like:

`Unknown type name 'NSArray'` or `Unknown type name 'NSError'`

The imports in the Objective-C file where I'm trying to use this framework essentially look like this (i.e. Foundation *is* being imported before trying to import the swift framework):

```
@import Foundation;
#import <OtherNonSystemHeaders.h>
#import "ThisFilesHeader.h"
#import "MyFramework-Swift.h"
```

If I open up the header file that Xcode generates there's a section about 150 lines down that looks like this:

```
#if __has_feature(modules)
@import ObjectiveC;
#endif
```

And if I manually change it to this it will compile and run.

```
#if __has_feature(modules)
@import ObjectiveC;
@import Foundation;
#endif
```

Obviously that's not a real solution since it gets overwritten any time Xcode regenerates that header, but I can't understand why turning off @objc inference is causing that import to disappear. I have manually marked certain methods as @objc, all the classes in the framework subclass NSObject, and each file imports Foundation.

I thought this might be a bug, but this happens both with Xcode 9.2 and 9.3, and clearly people are able to turn off @objc inference since it's now a recommended setting. But I am truly at a loss.

Comment: Is the framework that fails to compile or the target that uses the framework?

Comment: @sealos The framework itself does compile, but the file that it's being included in does not. I'll update the question to make that clear.

Comment: Is Foundation linked on the framework target?

Comment: @Sealos Ordinarily no (pretty sure it doesn't need to be?), but I have tried linking it and it made no difference.

Comment: Just import your framework as `@import MyFramework;` in Objective C code in this case (as far as I understand, it's an external framework). Also, you can check "Importing External Frameworks" section in the [Swift and Objective-C in the Same Project](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html) document.

Comment: @dive Just tried changing the `#include "MyFramework-Swift.h";` to `@import MyFramework;`. No difference.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you're missing `@import Foundation;` in your ObjC prior to:

```
#import "MyFramework-Swift.h"
```

ObjC files should `@import Foundation;` themselves. This is often also placed in the precompiled header (.pch) for performance reasons, but each `.m` should still import everything it needs, including Foundation.

Typically I recommend the following layout for `.m` files:

```
@import ...System Headers...

#import "Non-system framework headers"

#import "Local headers"

#import "Project-Swift.h"
```

Comment: I'll edit the question to make this more clear, but Foundation is imported in that ObjC file before the framework is imported. I thought maybe using @import rather than #import would do some kind of magic, but no difference. So I have my imports set up exactly as you describe and the problem still persists.

Answer (score 1):

We recently had to workaround what sounds like the same problem, although for us `@objc inference` didn't make a difference. Here is what we did:

In the MyFramework project, add a top-level header file `MyFramework.h` with just this one-liner:

`@import Foundation;`

Make sure that this file is added to each of the targets in your framework project as a Public header (not Private or Project... this part is important).

[image: Public]

Rebuild the framework. The generated `MyFramework-Swift.h` still won't `@import Foundation` but you will see the new `MyFramework.h` file right beside it in the built framework's `Headers` folder.

Import your framework into your app's Objective-C files using the same `#import <MyFramework/MyFramework-Swift.h>` syntax you're probably already using. You should no longer receive the `Unknown type name` errors.